How to redirect using the current website, not fixed
I'm using the code below, to redirect any page that does not exist, to a specific php scrip, to handle it :
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.example.com/handle.php?c=$0 [R=302,L] 

But what I want is, instead of typing https://www.example.com, I want to the rule to use the current website, not a fixed one, so I can use the same script in several domains.
I tried this :
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %{HTTP_HOST}%/handle.php?c=$0 [R=302,L] 

But it did not work.
Any ideas ?
Merry Christmas everyone !

That is the rewriting target pattern you would have to use: https://%{HTTP_HOST}/handle.php?c=$0. Or you use, as you correctly found out yourself, a path as rewriting target instead of a full URL.

Looks like i was overthinking ; this resolves my question :
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /handle.php?c=$0 [R=302,L] 


And that rule can be simplified to RewriteRule ^ /handle.php?c=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L] ...
